# Force update a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, var

I am building a website which has table with several inputs, and I need a specific variable to be updated every time a checkbox is pressed.
This is what a part of the table looks like:

[image: table image]

I have this javascript function to remove the readonly attribute from the respective input:

```
//Remove the readonly atribute when checkbox is checked
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("[id^='check_']")

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++){
    var checkbox = checkboxes[i];
    var inputId = checkbox.getAttribute("data-input-id");
    var inputElement = document.getElementById(inputId);
    (function(checkbox, inputElement){
        checkbox.addEventListener("change", function(){
            if (checkbox.checked){
                inputElement.removeAttribute("readonly")
            } else{
                inputElement.setAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
            };
        });
    })(checkbox, inputElement);
};
```

I was thinking i could reassign the variable inside this function but when I do it it says its value is never read even though I use it on other parts of the code below it.
Does anyone know how can I force update this variable.

**Note:** this is the variable

```
var NumberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]:not([readonly])');
```

**EDIT:** this variable is used on this part of the code

```
// Get all the number inputs in the table
var NumberInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]:not([readonly])');

// Save input values to localStorage whenever they change
NumberInputs.forEach(function(input){
    input.addEventListener('change', function(){
        localStorage.setItem(input.id, input.value);
    });
});

// Populate table with saved values when pages loads
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    NumberInputs.forEach(function(input){
        var SavedValue = localStorage.getItem(input.id);
        if (SavedValue){
            input.value = SavedValue;
        }
    });
});
```

And the problem is when i check the checkbox and then insert the value on the input after refreshing the checkbox state is populated into the table but the value is not, that value is only populated after refreshing the page and then insert the value again. I believe this happens because the variable is not updated after i check the checkbox but happens only on page load.

Comment: Your code doesn't mention `NumberInputs`. Please provide a [mcve] of your attempt.

Comment: Can't you recompute it inside of your event listener ?

Comment: Even if you changed what the variable contains - that will not change the fact, that you iterated over the _original_ element selection already, and added change handlers to all those fields. Trying to constantly change what elements do have a change handler attached and which don't - that makes rather little sense here. Just add a change handler to all of them, _once_ - and then inside your callback function, check if the element is currently set to `readonly` or not, and then proceed or don't proceed with what you need to do, based on that.